# Text content of file store in String not converting unicode to ISO_8859_1

Tags: java, unicode, iso-8859-1

I am trying to convert the Unicode into ISO_8859_1. It is quite easy when declaring the Unicode in the Java String variable, e.g.

```
String myString = "\u00E9checs";
byte[] bytesOfString = myString.getBytes();
String encoded_String = new String(bytesOfString, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
System.out.println(encoded_String);
```

Ouput:

```
échecs
```

So far so good, but when I try to convert the same text saved in a file, it's not converting just printing as it is, here I am enclosing the code to read from the file and perform conversions.

```
    String path = "st.txt"; //where st.txt contains only one line i.e. \u00E9checs
    FileInputStream inputStream = null;
    Scanner sc = null;
    try {
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(path);
        sc = new Scanner(inputStream);
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            byte[] bytesOfString = sc.nextLine().getBytes();   
            String encoded_String = new String(bytesOfString, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
            System.out.println(encoded_String); 
        
        }

        if (sc.ioException() != null) {
            throw sc.ioException();
        }
    } finally {
        if (inputStream != null) {
            inputStream.close();
        }
        if (sc != null) {
            sc.close();
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
\u00E9checs
```

Note:
This is a test code, therefore I am using a single line in a file; I need to apply the same procedure on a large file, for that I am using Scanner Class to save the memory utilization.

Could anyone guide me on how to achieve the same result for the text in a file as I am getting when the Unicode directly declare in the Java String variable?

Thank you in advance and looking forward to your early response.

Comment: Does the one line in your file contain the text `échecs` or `\u00E9checs`?   Is the first character `é` or a backslash?  I could not reproduce your problem if it contained `échecs` in ISO-8859-1.

Comment: `\u00E9` is the representation Java uses for a Unicode character. Step through your first example with a debugger and see what myString.getBytes() returns. That's what you need to put in a UTF8 encoded file to get `échecs`

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem:

```
      byte[] bytesOfString = sc.nextLine().getBytes();
      String encoded_String = new String(bytesOfString, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
```

So:

- there are some 8859-1 bytes in a file
- the scanner reads them under the assumption they're Unicode
- you then convert the Unicode data into some UTF-8 bytes
- and then convert the bytes into Unicode in the pretense that they're 8859-1

You should use a Scanner that expects 8859-1 input:

```
  new Scanner(inputstream, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
```

and then nextLine will do the correct conversion; no more code-juggling is needed.